# push notification payload with groups in Android

Tags: android, push-notification

I have requirement to group push for different sections. Like if title include G1 and other push with title G2 then two different push notification need to delivered on same handset

```
string message = "group";
string alertValue = "sports";
push.QueueNotification(android.WithJson("{ alert : " + message + ", alertValue: " + alertValue + " }"));
```

Above code might be working in iPhone but it is not working in Android it is giving Invalid JSON error. I want payload for android for grouping push notifications.

Answer (score 0):

i am not so sure but i think that you will have to send notifications separately because push notification is received and displayed by Android OS. so you cant control it on device, you will have to send it separately from server if you want to display it separately on device.

this tutorial could also help you.
https://developer.stackmob.com/tutorials/android/Push-Notifications

Thanks.